# OLAP Cube MDX calculation returns 0 when value is set

Tags: mdx, olap

I have a dimension ship that has speedinKM  but when i look in the cube browser the calculation does not return the expected value. The data from the dimension shows up in the cube browser but returns 0 in the calculation. does anyone know what the problem can be?

```
//[travel time]
[D Ship].[Speed In Km H] + 10
```

[image]

[image: [Cube browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw4sd.png)]

[image: [Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCkRw.png)]

i tried rebuilding the cube and reloading the data from the data warehouse but its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to extract the member's value from the `[D Ship]` dimension I think being more specific about this extraction might help:

```
[D Ship].[Speed In Km H].CURRENTMEMBER.MemberValue  + 10
```